# Flex mobile 4.6 ReferenceError: Error #1065

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, referenceerror

I really need some help here. I am working on a Flex mobile Project.
All of a sudden, the app throws a runtime error #1605.
The errormessage tells me, that it can not find `LabelItemRenderer` in the spark package.

I tried to create a new projet and to copy all my sources over to the new project.
At first this worked fine but after 1-3 compilations, I got the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm in the final phase of a project, which needs to be done until end of the week.

Here is a part of the stack trace:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable spark.components::LabelItemRenderer is not defined.
at spark.skins.mobile::ListSkin/createChildren()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobiletheme\src\spark\skins\mobile\ListSkin.as:132]
at mx.core::UIComponent/initialize()
```

Comment: ok i´ve found a clue where the error comes from. iits defenitley the spark listskin which causes the error. i have a list component in my mxml file and if i delete the list from my VGroup the error dosent occure. Iam also using the eskimo framework

Comment: iam using the latest version of flash builder. But i solved the problem. I dont know why but the compiler didnt include the Class LabelItemRenderer. But i had included the spark SWC. To solve the problem i declared a dummy property (private var dummy:LabelItemrenderer). Now the compiler inluded the class and the problem was solved. This solution is pretty hacky but it did the trick for me.

Comment: Ah, did you use reflections to instantiate the LabelItemRenderer?  Then you always have to have a reference declared somewhere, otherwise the compiler won't know the class is needed.  I usually keep one class where I declare and import all the types I use per `getDefinitionByName`.

Comment: Can you tell me what a reflection actually is? I just used a list componjent in my MXML View-component.

Comment: "Reflections" is the term used for dynamically specifying an object type at runtime (use a string to look up a class).  But obviously, you didn't use one ;)  Can you post your MXML code?  It would be interesting to find out why this happened.

Comment: Thank you Usch!  I was looking for this answer yesterday.  I gave up and went a different route because I couldn't find ANY information.  I'm using Flex 4.6 & eSkimo also.  All I did was drop in a list and it started telling me that it couldn't find LabelItemRenderer. ...Uggh!  I didn't think to try any hacks, because it's the DEFAULT renderer for a List!  Of course the compiler needs it!  I didn't tell it to use IconItemRenderer or a custom one... Hack or no hack.  All I wanted to do was keep moving. =)  Thanks again!